# Blender 2.9 python Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect

Tags: python

I'm a bpy beginner and i'm facing a error with python scripting on the line

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/blender-2.90.1-linux64/2.90/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

The code :

```
import bpy

Opsobj = bpy.ops.object

Scene = bpy.context.scene
Opsobj.select_all(action="SELECT")
Opsobj.delete(use_global=False)

target = 'jacket'
file_loc="/root/file.fbx"
bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=file_loc)
so = bpy.context.active_object


for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    obj.select_set(False)
bpy.data.objects[target].select_set(True)

Scene.objects[target].select_set(True)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')   <--- error here
```

I want to edit the jacket objectpy.context.scene.objects.active
How do i select the right context to be able to do the operation?

Comment: Some objects are not editable, an empty for example.  Make sure the acitve object is set, `context.view_layer.objects.active = context.scene.objects.get(target)` making it the active object to be edited.  If there is no object named target it will be None and also fail.  After an import (generally) the imported objects are also `context.selected_objects`.  Rarely use `bpy.data.objects` which is all objects in blend file whether linked to context scene or any scene.

Comment: @batFINGER yes, after I manually delete an object, my script will fail, unless I make some known object active, even if I have to make it (or some other) active again just after the mode_set(). thx!